# Spring xml primary bean

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

I try to get a bean with a primary attribute when another one is defined with the same parent.
I have 2 bean, BeanA and BeanB

```
package com.test.test.bean;

public class BeanA extends ABean {
    @Override
    public String getConfig() {
        return "BeanA";
    }
}
```

```
package com.test.test.bean;

public class BeanB extends ABean {
    @Override
    public String getConfig() {
        return "BeanB";
    }
}
```

Those two bean have the same parent ABean.

When I define them like that

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <bean id="com.test.test.bean.BeanA" class="com.test.test.bean.BeanA"  primary="false"/>

    <bean id="com.test.test.bean.BeanB" class="com.test.test.bean.BeanB" primary="true"/>

</beans>
```

And I call them with

```
package com.test.test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.test.test.bean.ABean;
import com.test.test.bean.BeanA;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-beantest.xml");
        ABean bean = context.getBean(ABean.class);
        System.out.println(bean.getConfig());
    }

}
```

I get the error :

*No unique bean of type [com.test.test.bean.ABean] is defined: expected single bean but found 2: com.test.test.bean.BeanA,com.test.test.bean.BeanB*

So the question is why the primary attribute don't enable to select only the com.test.test.bean.BeanB bean ?

Comment: Primary only applies to beans of the same type, so multiple beans of type `BeanB` not for supertypes.

Comment: Ok but if I try to do the same with as spring context : 

`<bean id="com.test.test.bean.BeanA" class="com.test.test.bean.BeanB"  primary="false"/>
 <bean id="com.test.test.bean.BeanB" class="com.test.test.bean.BeanB" primary="true"/>`

And call 

`BeanB bean = context.getBean(BeanB.class);`

I have the same result :

No unique bean of type [com.test.test.bean.BeanB] is defined: expected single bean but found 2: com.test.test.bean.BeanA,com.test.test.bean.BeanB

Comment: The **primary** identifier also applies only for autowiring, so not for `getBean` calls. So if you use autowiring by type, it will resolve to the primary one. Using `getBean` will just lookup a single bean.